# How can I provide semantic information about a ROM to a RAM project in IAR

Tags: iar

I am trying to make an IAR project for a RAM based image containing code that will call into ROM code.
ROM here is literally ROM, not flash. I know that I can do this as I have the source ELF file that was used to generate the ROM and I have extracted the symbols from the ROM's elf and provided them to IAR which keeps the linker happy. The problem is that the symbol information I am providing to IAR this way is just a symbol name to address mapping.

What I'd like to be able to achieve is to provide more semantic information to IAR such that when I am debugging the RAM image and it steps into ROM, I retain the ability to do source level debugging.
Kind of like the ability to retain full semantic debugging when single stepping through a DLL in application land. Is such a thing possible in IAR?

Not as important but still very valuable would be the ability to have the linker check against signature discrepancies between the ROM and the calling RAM.

Out of curiosity is this possible in other tools like with ARM GCC, Keil etc?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be possible using `isymexport`.

This PDF includes info on the tool:
http://supp.iar.com/FilesPublic/UPDINFO/004916/arm/doc/EWARM_DevelopmentGuide.ENU.pdf